# How do you enable a script while releasing the mouse & colliding with another game object?

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to have it so when you click and drag on the object it disables its motion scripts. That part is done. However when I place it back in a certain gameobject window I want it to snap into place and begin the motion script again. I can get it to snap but it does not want to reenable the script.

Here is the code for attempting to reenable the script that doesn't work.

```
public class snap : MonoBehaviour {  
public GameObject mass;
public harmonic scriptH;
public DrawLine scriptD;
public GameObject spring;


void Start() {
    scriptH = mass.GetComponent<harmonic>();
    scriptD = spring.GetComponent<DrawLine>();
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) { 


    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("mass")) { 
        other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(transform.position); 
        scriptH.enabled = true;
        scriptD.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

The position transform works but not the script enable. Here is the mouse dragging script though I think I narrowed it down to the point where it is not the problem.

```
public void OnMouseDown()
{
    isDragging = true;
}

public void OnMouseUp()
{
    isDragging = false;

}

void Update()
{
    if (isDragging) {
        Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        transform.Translate(mousePosition);  
      //  scriptH.enabled = false;
      //  scriptP.enabled = false;
      //  scriptD.enabled = false;            

    }
```

I am currently beginning with the scripts as disabled and removed the disabling portion in Update(). The first script(snap) still does not enable the scripts on collision. I tried OnTriggerStay as well as OnTriggerEnter, the box does transform position so I know the collision is registering but do not understand why the script enabling does not work.

They are in different game objects so is it an issue with my declaring the scripts wrong in the first script?

EDIT: Turns out even disabling the first script the box still snaps into position because it is colliding with the gameobject so seems nothing in my first script works. So any input on why the collision doesn't trigger would be appreciated.

Comment: Not a full answer, but won't your OnTriggerEnter fire and if you are still dragging your object it deactivates it again? I'm not even sure if OnTriggerEnter is not only called once, so for a very brief time your script may be active just be to shot down again. You could change your second script that you disable it only once (make a start dragging function) and check if your first script enables it correctly again, after that you can work forwards to the correct handling of the interaction. (Or disable the isDragging when you hit OnTriggerEnter)

Comment: Presumably you tried putting `scriptH.enabled = true; scriptP.enabled = true; scriptD.enabled = true;` right after `isDragging = false;` - how did the results differ from what you want?

Comment: @DMGregory That does reenable the script, but the issue is I only want the scripts to enable only when the box is dragged into a gameobject box which is attempted to be done in the first script  portion. I believe that does reenable the scripts but they become disabled again in the next frame because of whats in update in the second. I may have a fix by combining the two and OnMouseUp I enable if the two gameobjects currently occupy the same space

Comment: Great. If that solution solves your problem, post it as an answer below. If not, edit your question to show how you tried implementing it and where it's still giving you trouble.

Comment: You are aware that OnTriggerEnter and similar methods run on disabled scripts too, right? Just want to make sure I'm understanding your remarks in your edit correctly...

Comment: @DMGregory I was not aware of that. So the transformation in the OnTriggerEnter may be running even when that scripts disabled? I just put a debug log to write when that triggers however and see nothing. Even with the script removed from the gameobject the box still moves so I believe it is just moving based on it colliding with the game object if that makes sense.  I am currently working on going about this a different way and will update the post again after it (hopefully) works

Comment: If the object is moving due to something not shown in your question, then you need to edit your question to show that before we can help you with it. Please verify that your question contains a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the issue: you should be able to create a new, empty project, and using only the content you've written in your question, reproduce the problem you're experiencing.